# Binding with or condition

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

i have two `check boxes` and a `text box`. the text box's `IsEnabled` property should be binded to both of those check box's `IsChecked` Properties. if one of check box or both of them are enabled then text box should be enabled.
the first solution that came to my mind was `multibinding`. But it needs another class to do. Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with two `DataTriggers` on TextBox Style where you can enable TextBox in case any checkBox is checked.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox2"/>
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox1}"
                    Value="True">
           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox2}"
                     Value="True">
           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think not - I would really like "and" or "or" expressions in xmal, but they are not provided.
I stumpled upon this library, which claims to add them:
http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/
But I never used them extensively.